# optimize a function using Tensorflow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I have a loss function that contains three sums 
as the following:

```
sum for each j in words:

   sum for each i in documents:

        sum for each r in Tj
```

the problem that I have in implementing this is that Tj is a list of lists, in which each list has a different length.
I tried to implement it as a  numpy function and then use tf.py_func, but now I don't know how to optimise it.

def loss_fun(COM, Wj, Wi, B, R, Tj):

```
def loss_factor(j):

    L = R.shape[0]

    sum_container = []
    for l in range(L):     

       third_sum  = 0
       for i in range(len(Tj[j])):     

           entity_value = Tj[j][i]
           wi = np.reshape(Wi[entity_value], [1, 300])
           Rl = R[l,:,:]
           wj = np.reshape(Wj[j,:], [1, 300])

           wiRl = tf.matmul(wi, Rl)
           wjRl = tf.matmul(wj, Rl)

           wiRlxwjRl = np.matmul(wiRl, np.transpose(wjRl))
           pmi = COM[entity_value, j]
           bj = B[j,0]

           distance_expr = np.square( (wiRlxwjRl + bj - pmi) )
           third_sum = third_sum + distance_expr

       sum_container.append(third_sum)

    return(np.amin(sum_container) / len(Tj[j]))



L = R.shape[0]
M = B.shape[0]
p = -2

first_sum  = 0
second_sum = 0
third_sum  = 0

for j in range(M):

     sigma = loss_factor(j)
     sigma = 1/sigma

     second_sum = 0
     for l in range(L):    

       third_sum  = 0
       for i in range(len(Tj[j])):     

           entity_value = Tj[j][i]
           wi = np.reshape(Wi[entity_value], [1, 300])
           Rl = R[l,:,:]
           wj = np.reshape(Wj[j,:], [1, 300])

           wiRl = tf.matmul(wi, Rl)
           wjRl = tf.matmul(wj, Rl)

           wiRlxwjRl = np.matmul(wiRl, np.transpose(wjRl))
           pmi = COM[entity_value, j]
           bj = B[j,0]

           distance_expr = np.square( (wiRlxwjRl + bj - pmi) )
           third_sum = third_sum + distance_expr

        second_sum = second_sum + np.power(third_sum, p)

    first_sum = first_sum + sigma * second_sum


nuc_norm = 0
lambdaa = 0.1
for l in range(L):        
    Rl = R[l,:,:]
    nuc_norm = nuc_norm + np.linalg.norm(Rl, ord = 'nuc')

nuc_norm = lambdaa * nuc_norm

return (first_sum + nuc_norm)
```

######end of the loss func

```
K = 50

COM = tf.constant(co_occurrence_matrix, name = 'COM')
Tj  = tf.constant(t_j, name = 'Tj')
Wj  = tf.Variable(Wj, name = 'Wi')

Wi  = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([len(entities_list), 300], 1.0, -1.0), name = 'Wi')    
B   = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([len(features_list)-1, 1], 1.0, -1.0), name = 'B')
R   = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape = (K, 300, 300)), name = 'R')


loss_val = tf.py_func(loss_fun, [COM, Wj, Wi, B, R, Tj], tf.float32)

optimizer = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(0.01).minimize(loss_val)
```

I will appreciate any idea

Comment: I don't advise using py_func, since it will not have gradients without using Graph.gradient_override_map (see [this issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1095)). Instead, I would try to implement the specific loss function using tf.reduce_sum if possible. Perhaps, including code for loss_fun would be helpful.

Comment: I add the loss function

Comment: It seems like it might be a bit over-complicated and would be an absolute pain to calculate the gradients manually. It looks like all of the operations you use are available in tensorflow, so that is what you are going to have to do. I would avoid using for loops and use tf.reduce_sum.

Comment: yes put the problem is that the tj iteration is different each time

Comment: Since you are storing Tj as a tf.constant, it has to fit inside a tensor.